# How to attach "bar code" and "QA code" through mail in mfmailcomposer in ios

Tags: ios, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller, mfmailcomposer

I have one Bar code as an Image and QA Code in Web View.these are generated depends on user input data(id and name).
Now I want to send these two things through mail using Mfmailcomposer.
How to attach these two things to mail and send to others.

Thanks.

Comment: Create pdf. and add bar code to .pdf file and attach to mfMailComposer

Comment: Here i have bar code image in one view,and QA code (web view) in another view.How to both as taken in single pdf file?